# How do I select one window without opening others?

Tags: 11.04, unity

Unity comes with so much changes. Some features are good but I am getting problem with multiple windows management. When I used to open multiple windows and click on icon to show one of them then all the open windows comes up.

Right-click does not work like docky to select one window. It is just disturbing. Suppose I am working on firefox and need one of the opened file browsers. When click all nautilus comes-up.

What is the method to select one of the window without open others. I am doing wrong or unity do not have any good management system. Please help.

Comment: My understanding is that you have a starting situation like [this](http://i.imgur.com/BA7Cg.png), when you click the Firefox icon you get [this](http://i.imgur.com/zMgGk.png), but you would like to know how to get [this](http://i.imgur.com/nwAfy.png). Is that correct?

Comment: Based on user17118 comment to my answer, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/740862 suggests your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am not suer I understand your question and what is it that you are trying to do. Is that that you want to switch between windows of only one application. Say that tou have one firefox and three nautilus windows open and want to switch between the windows of nautilus?If so, install compizconfig-settings-manager  (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`) and configure Static application switcher plugin - settings for group are those that are of your interest.

Comment: I have two nautilus opened(computer and home). When firefox is open then [link] http://i1221.photobucket.com/albums/dd479/shantanucse18/firefox.png. When i click on nautilus to focus computer then it shows both like this [link] http://i1221.photobucket.com/albums/dd479/shantanucse18/nautilus.png . But i need to select one what i want.

Comment: I see. Then I think tobi's answer is right. I.e., it is not currently implemented. Or you can circumvent it by using the alt-tab shorcut.

Comment: i think i found a way. double click on launcher appear all opened windows in expo mode and select one from them will focus only one not all. But it is difficult to find desire instance from expo.

Comment: do your know,  how to show extra big title in expo mode (manually or using compiz)?

Comment: No I do not know, but glad you found a way to do what you want.